# Image uploader closes when you press ESC from within the file selection dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader

If I press my <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the File Selection dialog after clicking the upload area, both the file explorer *and* the uploader dialog are closed. This is consistent on both Chrome and Firefox. I think only the file explorer should be closed.

Can the <kbd>Esc</kbd> press please not propagate down to the uploader? Note than when clicking the "Cancel" button, the uploader is not being closed.

Comment: You have some pretty serious data on key-press timings. Does this have to do with some sort of custom configuration due to.. restraints? Why are you needing to press esc?

Comment: How is this a bug? It used to be like that from the beginning, and Escape is standard key to abort actions. You can turn this into feature request, but I'll still disagree. I want a quick way to abort the dialog.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it could still abort the dialogue - but if I escape from the browse window, why would I want to close the upload as well?

Comment: Oops, my bad. For some reason I mistook "browse window" as "browser window" thinking you mean when focus is on the uploader. Agree the ESC key press should not propagate further.

Comment: OK, changed your bug report a bit. It's really not relevant that if you press the key faster than light it's "working" - no sane person will do that. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, I was thinking it in my head and ummm... forgot to write it down :)

Comment: I've retracted my comment, as it makes sense now :) - It seemed like you were saying you needed the escape key to only work within some bonkers time frame :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build (3525 on MSE/MSO, 2683 on other sites).